# Excluding words in Word cloud

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words, word-cloud

I am trying to exclude some extra words from nltk stopwords library for spanish words but whenever i apply the following code is not reflected in the final world of cloud. I believe is related to the list structure which is not being really aplied the words filter criteria but i cannot realized why.

```
lines

['Comment Message\n',
'Aprovechamiento polÃ\xadtico , estÃ¡s publicaciones no ayudan en nada,  no veo que ustedes y sus 
partidos polÃ\xadticos estÃ©n haciendo algo,  solo sembrando discordia y odio, estamos en tiempos 
difÃ\xadciles y esto no aporta,  y recuerden que tambiÃ©n son parte de los ricos,  y no he visto que 
se metan la mano al bolsillo y repartir. Hay muchas personas con depresiÃ³n y angustia y esto no 
aporta en nada\n',
'\n',
'Que pena que el agua que es un recurso natural lo tengamos algunos pocos agua para toda la gente que 
lo necesite lo exigimos ahora ya\n',
'Y los malditos de barrio ALTO LADRONES tienen de todo Sodre todos los esclavos de PiÃ±era y mas\n',
'No hay derecho\n',
'AGUA para todos los chilenos ahora!!!!\n',
'Todos estos chanchos culiaos que nos roban hasta lo mÃ¡s bÃ¡sico.. fuera piÃ±era 
conchetumadre...\n',
'PiÃ±era ya te diste el lujo de ser presidente de la republica de Chile no eres politico eres 
empresario por lo tanto piensas y actuas como empresario por respeto a quienes votaron por ti da un 
paso al costado toma tu dinero que no fue ganado con sacrificio si no con estafas y vete a otro pais 
y deja vivir a los chilenos de corazon vivir como queremos vivir EN PAZ\n',
'No se queden somitidos por la constitucion, hecha por un gobierno dictatorial y genocida, 
despierten.\n',
'No puede ser gobierno corrupto devuelvan El Agua al Pueblo\n',
'HÃ¡ganlo saber por TV y YouTube a la organizaciÃ³n mundial de la salud.... OMS...\n',
'SeÃ±or..te suplicÃ³ del fondo de mi alma que mandes lluvia para tu pueblo y misericordi por este 
hombre que tenemos como presidente. ..Que nos damos cuenta que estÃ¡ ciego, sordo y mudo ...estamos 
sÃ³lo en esta tierra sÃ³lo tÃº  Padre mÃ\xado dueÃ±o del Sol de la Luna del Viento. .de la vida y la 
muerte ..ven pronto a nuestra ayuda. ..\n',

and continues .... ]
```

To this `list` i apply the following function

```
def remove_stopwords(words):
     """Remove stop words from list of tokenized words"""
       new_words = []

       stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('spanish')
       newStopWords = ['que','el','del','es','la'  , 'de','un','son','tambien','porque', 'cuando' , 
       'lo' , 'su' , 'pueden' ,'hacer' , 'le' , 'esto' , 'nadie' , 'yo' , 'chile' , 'mas' , 'hasta' , 
       'por' , 'da' , 'mi' , 'ni' ,'estan' , 'todo' , 'el ' , 'con' , 'por' , 'para' , 'la ' , 'eso' 
       , 'nos' , 'dio' , 'ello' , 'es ' ,'un ' , 'tu' , 'donde' , 'solo' , 'nosotros' , 'mas ','hace' 
       , 'toda' , 'toda ', 'si' , 'si ','lo ' , 'lo' , 'que ' , 'la' , 'tener' , ' tener' , ' la' , ' 
       que' , ' de' , ' una' , 'todo' , 'son','esta' , 'cual' , 'desde' ,' desde' , 'nada' , 'esa' , 
       'eso' ,' de ' , 'de ' ,'te','alguna',' lo','cuando', ' donde' , ' como ' , ' como' , 'como' , 
       'como ']
       stopwords.extend(newStopWords)

       for word in words:
         if word not in stopwords:
            new_words.append(word)

       return new_words

 remove_stopwords(lines)
```

It doesnt do anything and i still having the excluded words in `lines`. I believe maybe it's because i didnt tokenize `lines` but whenever i apply :

```
 word_tokens = word_tokenize(lines)
```

this error is shown:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```